# How to generate 7 pseudorandom numbers with seed in 1 execution in java

Tags: java

Question is: Seed is 10L, Generate and print 7 pseudorandom integer values between 0 (inclusive) and 200 (exclusive).

Code I tried:

```
public static int randomGenerator() {
    Random generator = new Random(10L);
    return generator.nextInt(200 - 0) + 0;
}

System.out.println(randomGenerator());
```

Comment: Just call `nextInt` seven times (on the same `generator`, don't make a new one).

Comment: While it's obvious what the problem is from looking at your code, always be sure to specify what the output/error is, and what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

To produce 7 numbers, you have to call the `nextInt` method 7 times without creating a new `Random` instance. To return all 7 values "in one execution", you need to return an array or a `List`.

I would also recommend giving your method some parameters, so that it isn't tied to those specs.

```
public static int[] getRandomInts(long seed, int amount, int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int[] nums = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

In Java 8, the `Random` class has the alternative [`ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) method that returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
public static int[] getRandomInts(long seed, int amount, int min, int max) {
    return new Random(seed).ints(amount, min, max).toArray();
}
```

Then in your calling scope iterate over the numbers to print them.